# What would be the "GPU version" of the numpy.fft package in python?

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, gpu, fft

I want to compute the fft of a big signal (big sample size) at a shorter span of time (thus, GPU). I have tried the following modules:

- `PyFFT` - does not support 2D transforms and non powers of 2
- `gpyfft` - transform size is also not arbitrary (powers of 2, 3, 5)
- `scikits.cuda` - only returns N/2+1 coefficients. would be problematic
  when taking transforms of complex inputs
- `numpy.fft` - arbitrary inputs, complete transform, supports 2d
  transforms

What would be the python wrapped "GPU version" of the numpy.fft package? (Optional: Can it be CUDA based?)

Comment: It appears you are asking for a software recommendation, which would be off-topic here.

Comment: I'd just like to know if such software exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you want CUDA based library for computing FFT, where the transform size is arbitrary, and support 1D, 2D, and 3D FFTs; then you may need to have a look at cuFFT. 
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/#axzz410MycIFQ

Note: this is cuda based library, not python.

Comment: I wanted python wrapped implementation actually. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @JoshuaSantiago: the scikits.cuda you already listed is a direct wrapper of cuFFT. This is *the* canonical FFT implementation for CUDA GPUs

Comment: I have already used cuFFT and it returns the whole transform. Why does scikits.cuda only return N/2+1? I lose information when transforming complex data.

Comment: Is this because the output is conjugate symmetric?